# How to use crosswalk/xwalk in my react-native project?

Tags: react-native, crosswalk, xwalkview

I want to use crosswalk to solve webview's problem, but I don't know how to add crosswalk into my react-native project.
I wish somebody can give me the details for adding crosswalk and provide an example of the xwalkview's usage.
Thanks!

Comment: Please try and come back with specific problems.

Comment: In case someone is still looking, here is a native module for adding crosswalk to react-native: https://github.com/jordansexton/react-native-webview-crosswalk